# SSLEngine handshaking stuck after task

Tags: java, ssl, nio, handshake, sslengine

I use example from http://books.google.com/books?id=l6f1jTB_XCYC&lpg=PA185&vq=scalable%20secure&pg=PA185#v=onepage&q&f=false to see how SSLEngine works with SocketChannel. Later i wanted to create solution adapted to my implementation. Unfortunately, this example does not work. It's stuck after runDelegatedTasks() method executing. Server console output:

```
Server: listening at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl[/0.0.0.0:12345]
Server: select count=1
Server: accepted java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:12345 remote=/127.0.0.1:52793]
Server: select count=1
Server: reading
Server: read count=0 request=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16660 cap=16660]
```

Client console is empty.

Anyone can help with this example?

Comment: There's an updated version of the code at http://dadaelectronics.asia/wipv3_6/page2/show.jsp?id=230165&db=Entries

Comment: Unfortunately page doesn't work. Maybe you have better example implementation of SSLEngine with SocketChannel or maybe you have updated version of this example?

Comment: The [link](http://dadaelectronics.asia/wipv3_6/files/114/file/23/Net-Source.zip) now works. This *is* my 'better example'. I wrote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, the `SSLEngineManager` code in my book had a bug when used in client mode. The source code was updated shortly after publication and has been made available [here](http://dadaelectronics.asia/wipv3_6/files/114/file/23/Net-Source.zip) until further notice.

Esmond Pitt, author *Fundamental Networking in Java.*